# Loading gif image while jQuery ajax is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to show a loading image while my ajax call is running, however using the `beforeSend` attribute is not changing my result area.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/answer_checker.php",
  global: false, type: "POST", 
  data: ({...clipped...}), 
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#response').text('Loading...');
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $('#response').html(html);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your other options, for example is it `async: false` by chance?

Comment: `global: false, type: "POST", data: ({...}), cache: false` I'm not using `async`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a solution, it may not be the best way to do it but it has worked in this case.

```
$('input').keyup(function () {

  $('#response').text('loading...');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/answer_checker.php",
    global: false, type: "POST", 
    data: ({...clipped...}), 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $('#response').html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

By setting the resonce content before calling the ajax function it remains showing the loading text until the ajax call updates the same content.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer.

Alan

Comment: this is easy and simple way to do, i do the same always

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem.  To resolve my issue, I replaced the .text, in the beforeSend section, with .html and created a html tag to insert into the element that holds my status.  The success function did not replaced the content created by the .text() function but it did replace content created by the .html() function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/answer_checker.php",
  global: false, type: "POST", 
  data: ({...clipped...}), 
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#response').html("<img src='/images/loading.gif' />");
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $('#response').html(html);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You <strike>are</strike> were missing a comma after `cache: false`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I just added the extra options I was using.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following:

```
$('#tblLoading').ajaxStart(function() { $(this).show(); });
$('#tblLoading').ajaxComplete(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```