# How do I load an image while waiting for AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I could get some pointers. I am trying to use a loading gif while getting a response from an ajax request. The issue I am running into is that it will not display the gif while sending an email.

I have looked at several pages on here to try and find a solution but none of them seems to be working. These are the pages I have looked at: [Loading gif image while jQuery ajax is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448955/loading-gif-image-while-jquery-ajax-is-running) and [Display loading image while post with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509711/display-loading-image-while-post-with-ajax) and [Show loading image while $.ajax is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed)

I have used the following code to try and achieve this:

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
$(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
$(this).hide();
});
```

This does not show the gif, I have also tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "contact1.php",
 data: dataString,
 beforeSend: loadStart,
 complete: loadStop,
 success: function() {
  $('#form').html("<div id='msg'></div>");
  $('#msg').html("Thank you for your email. I will respond within 24 hours. Please reload the page to send another email.")
 },
 error: function() {
  $('#form').html("<div id='msg'></div>");
  $('#msg').html("Please accept my apologies. I've been unable to send your email. Reload the page to try again.")
 }
}); 
return false;
});
function loadStart() {
  $('#loading').show();
}
function loadStop() {
  $('#loading').hide();
}
```

I have also tried putting $("#loading").show() before the ajax request and unsing .hide() in the success and error functions. I still get nothing showing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually you need to do this by listening ajaxStart and Stop events and binding it to the `document`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#loading").show();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loading").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
});

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.text').text('');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://api.meetup.com/2/cities",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.text').text('Meetups found: ' + data.results.length);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#loading { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
<p class="text"></p>
<div id="loading">
  <!-- You can add gif image here 
  for this demo we are just using text -->
  Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: Would this wait for very heavy content to be loaded?

Comment: What does this do to the html? where does it add the "#loading"? Looks like css id but to what div? or does it add an empty div like: `<div id="#loading"></div>`

Comment: @MichaelRogers the idea is to have an element on your page with the `#loading` id so that it is shown and hidden when the Ajax call starts and stops, respectively.  See the code snippet and there's a div with the id.  It is hidden by default in this pretty awesome answer.

Comment: Without button how to load ajax loader. I have three dropdowns, first and second user input and the third one auto response based on the first two dropdowns, here how can i load ajax loader? @palaѕн

Comment: Could you please create an online demo ([**mwe**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) for it, so that I can look into it and provide you with some info regarding it. Thanks!