# Take an action only after AJAX has loaded all bytes of new content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to bring from the server some content using AJAX, I don't know how long it might take to load as some times it might be heavy. So I created a loading gif that appears everytime I call the AJAX function, but I want to fade it out once the AJAX response is loaded and fade in the content division.

HTML

```
<div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

This is what I am trying:

```
$(elm).click(function(){
  $('#loading').show();
  $('#content').fadeOut();
  $.ajax({
      url:'posts.php'
      data:{id:id_post},
      method:"POST",
      success:function(response){
        $('#content').load(response, function(){
          $('#content').html(response);
          $('#content').fadeIn();
          $('#loading').hide();
        });
      }
  });
});
```

I know it is wrong because in `.load(param1, function(data){})`, param1 should be a reference file to load and not a variable with a string, it seems to work, but `console.log(data)` returns me a not found error, so I am sure this is not the way to do it.

In short words: **I want to fadeIn() my div and fadeOut() my loading if and only if every byte of the AJAX response is loaded, not if the code is ready, but loaded, for example a big image inside an `<img>` tag.**

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Use a setTimeout and call an external function with the response arguments?
You could also use the jQuery AJAX events like ajaxStart and ajaxStop to do this also.

Comment: Your doing to ajax calls? One with $.ajax, and then another with $.load?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want because load will set content of element with the response, but you set it using .html() too, then  you fadeIn this element to instantly hide it. Quite strange logic, isn't it?!

Comment: Exaclty @PaulKnopf that is why I know there is an error, what is the way to do it?

Comment: @roasted I am not trying to use load as a way to insert code, I am tryong to wait for the content to load, I know my method is wrong, it works! But is wrong, that is why I am asking. thanks

Comment: Ha ok, you are confusing load event with load method which are not the same. There is no load event for div element. BTW, why should have it? And still i don't understand what you are trying to do, its just non sense as your code in success callback is already run when the ajax is done

Comment: Ok @roasted, I want to fadeIn() my division only and only if every byte of the AJAX response is loaded, not ready, loaded, I am not confusing the event with the method, I just dont know how to do it, that is my question. Thanks.

Comment: @EddyXP `$.load` act like an ajax request that will do like a `$.html(response)` when he is done. Apparently you just need an Ajax then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your AJAX response is a chunk of HTML that includes an `<img>` tag that you put on the page, and you want to detect when this image has been loaded, you should do something extra.

You should divide the response in the image to preload, and the raw html that uses the image. You could use a JSON response like this:

```
{
 "image": "url_to_big_image.jpg", 
 "html": "<img src=\"url_to_big_image.jpg\">"
}
```

Your favorite backend language probably has a way to convert your objects/arrays to JSON.

Then when your AJAX request has finished, you can do this:

```
var img = $('<img/>')
img[0].src = response.image // this pre-loads the image

img.load(function() {
    // now the image has been pre-loaded
    $('#content').html(response.html)
    $('#content').fadeIn()
    $('#loading').hide()
})
```

### Multiple images

To do this for multiple images you could put the images in an array in the JSON:

```
{
 "images": ["url_to_big_image.jpg", "second_image.jpg"], 
 "html": "<img src=\"url_to_big_image.jpg\"> <img src=\"second_image.jpg\">"
}
```

Then loop through them in javascript, and keep up how many have been loaded. If all images have been loaded you can show the content:

```
var show_content = function() {

    // only show content if all images are loaded
    if(images_loaded == response.images.length) {
        $('#content').html(response.html)
        $('#content').fadeIn()
        $('#loading').hide()
    }

}

var images_loaded = 0

for(var img_url in response.images) {

    var img = $('<img/>')
    img[0].src = img_url // preload image

    img.load(function() { // when image is pre-loaded
        images_loaded++ // increase images_loaded
        show_content() // show content if all images are loaded
    })

}
```

I haven't tested this code so it might be you need to change something to make it work, but it's about the idea.

Comment: This is very good, but the response might include more tags :(

Comment: Maybe it looked like it loads all images because after the first image that was loaded the other ones were loaded too, so you might want to have your script support multiple images anyway. I updated my answer to support multiple images. I haven't tested it so you might need to change some things to make it work, but it's about the idea. Hope this works for you.

Comment: This was great, thanks @rednaw, I just needed to find a way to send variables to the server, but I found that .load() can send variables as well in Json format. Thanks! I also found this: might be a faster way, I still need to test it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881626/loading-gif-while-waiting-for-ajax-response

Answer (score 1):

Based on [API](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you could do

```
$(elm).click(function(){
  $('#loading').show();
  $('#content').fadeOut();
  $('#content').load('posts.php',
          {id:id_post},
          function(response, status, xhr){
              $('#content').fadeIn();
              $('#loading').hide();
          }
   );
});
```

`$.load` already set the html of `#content` with the response.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `load` function loads data from a server and takes an url as first argument. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

So I think you should just do this:

```
success:function(response){
    $('#content').html(response)
    $('#content').fadeIn();
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't assure the content is loaded, the code will be ready but not loaded. a Big image will still load while the loading gif would be hidden.

Comment: I think the question was to take action after ajax has been loaded and not a big image in the ajax response

Comment: I asked the question, it could be a big image, or a tiny text.

Comment: I think you are getting it wrong. The `success` function is only being called after the ajax request has been done. If the response contains a big image, then it will still be called after the request is done. If however your reponse is a chunk of html and has a `<img>` tag in it with a external url to a big image, then it will still have to load this image.

Comment: This is quite a different matter. The browser starts up a seperate request to get the image. This is out of the scope of the ajax call.

Comment: See my new answer, I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this { not tested }:

```
success: function (response) {
     var $tmp = $($.trim(response)),
         $l_elems = $tmp.find('img, script'),  //find will not work if elements not nested inside a container. In this case use a fake div as container and nesting elements inside it
         tot = $l_elems.length,
         i = 0;
     $l_elems.one('load', function () { //here using one, not on
         i++;
         if (i === tot) {
             $('#loading').hide();
             $('#content').append($l_elems).fadeIn();
         }
     }).each(function () {
         if (this.complete) $(this).load();
     });
 }
```

Comment: If it is a big image for example, the loading gif will be gone and the div will fadeIn even if the image is not loaded. I want to wait for every byte to load before showing the content

Comment: sorry forgot to append elements