# Image not displaying after ob_flush()

Tags: php, image, flush

I have a PHP script that takes a long time to load data. Therefore I would like to display a loading indicator before loading is complete. I tried it like this:

```
<img src="images/loader.gif" />Loading ...
<?php
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5);
?>
Loading finished
```

but it is not working: The browser displays the text but doesn't load the image although the image tag including it's source attribute is displayed by the HTML inspector. I suspect that the browser (Opera) starts loading images only when the page is completely loaded. Can this be fixed?

Comment: you need to load the tricky part of the content through an ajax query. That way, it will still be long but asynchronous, and you could display a loading indicator as well. Checkout the numerous examples on this site or elsewhere on how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP output buffer not flushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751772/php-output-buffer-not-flushing)

Comment: You must use [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448955/loading-gif-image-while-jquery-ajax-is-running) beforeSend and success methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We used Ajax already but we were looking for a solution more simple. However obviously using Ajax is the best solution.