# jquery loading gif loads after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, loading

I am trying to fill a div with a loading gif.  When a user clicks on the search button, the first directive is to load the gif.  then do the ajax, and finally, replace loading gif with results.  What I am seeing in dev tools network tab, is that the loading gif is pending until the ajax call is done, completely defeating the purpose of the loading gif.  without the ajax call, the loading gif loads instantly.

```
$('body').on('click', '#searchForDids', function () {
  $('#results').html("<img src='images/loading.gif' width='250px'>");
  var npa = $('#npa').val();
  var nxx = $('#nxx').val();
  var consec = $('#consec').val();
  var token = $('#_token').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'npa': npa,
      'nxx': nxx,
      'consec': consec,
      '_token': token
    },
    url: "/telnyxSearch",
    success: function (result) {
      $('#results').html(result);
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
})
```

If I replace

```
$('#results').html("<img src='images/loading.gif' width='250px'>");
```

with:

```
$('#results').html('cat');
```

Cat shows up instantly, just as I would expect the loading gif to.  I know  the url to the image is correct.

Based on duplicate vote below I looked at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448955/loading-gif-image-while-jquery-ajax-is-running):

```
    $('body').on('click','#searchForDids',function(){
    var npa = $('#npa').val();
    var nxx = $('#nxx').val();
    var consec = $('#consec').val();
    var token = $('#_token').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{'npa' : npa,
              'nxx' : nxx,
              'consec' : consec,
              '_token' : token},
        url:"/telnyxSearch",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#results').html("<img src='images/loading.gif' width='250px'/>");
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#results').html(result);
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
})
```

I got the same results still..

Again:  If i use some random string it works fine, its only failing when i try to use the loading.gif image......

Comment: Close your `img` tag when appending with `/>`

Comment: same result......

Comment: The linked answer is not working....

Comment: question edited, proven to not be same question. please unduplicate so more eyes can assist.

Comment: ugh. when policing the resource goes to far, making the resource incredibly difficult to use...